# .bat file to check whether IIS is installed or not

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, windows-services

I am looking for a .bat file which checks whether IIS is installed or not.Below is the .bat file I created

```
@echo off
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp /v VersionString

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto NOT_EXISTS

:EXISTS
    echo "IIS installed.."
    goto:END
:NOT_EXISTS
    echo "IIS not installed..."
    goto:END
:END
```

This works fine in Windows 7 machine but this is not working in Windows Server 2012.

In the .bat file I am checking for the registry entry "VersionString" to see whether IIS is installed or not.

I tested this bat file in Windows Server 2012.I uninstalled IIS and after uninstalling IIS registry keys which are there for IIS(ex:VersionString) are not getting removed.So when I run the bat file it shows as IIS is installed.

So is there any better any to check if IIS is installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use sc to determine whether services are installed. Run `sc query` to get an idea of the kinds of information available, `sc /?` for a full run-down on sc capabilities.

```
sc query | findstr /C:"DISPLAY_NAME: World Wide Web Publishing Service"
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 echo IIS installed
```